# Get data from RSLinx and send to SQL Server through Visual Basic or C#?

Tags: sql-server, vba, opc

I have a question: can I write a program in VB or C# that gets data from RSLinx and sends it to SQL Server?

I have searched but only find information with programs with cost. I'm new in this.

Does someone know if this is even possible?

Comment: I don't know the application at all but according to the product page you should be able to get data from it via an OPC interface. I would Google "OPC client c#" if you haven't already

Comment: _____________________

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for VB or C# but I would use node-red.

If you are just looking to move data from a PLC to a database then take a look at Node-Red. Here is a video that should help you get started. Node-Red can do OPC-UA or just talk direct to the PLC with out the need for OPC in the middle it's your choice. If you need more help just ask!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaUmhhMdoyY

Node-Red can also do the GUI.

For the reporting you can use https://grafana.com/.

If you would like a good Database to log to look at https://www.timescale.com/.

Grafana and Timescale work well together!!

Answer (score 0):

www.advancedhmi.com is no cost and can read data from AB PLCs using VB.NET or C#. Also it does not need RSLinx.